# Access VBA using Multiple button.visible = False

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a login screen I am using to control access to buttons in my main Navigation form. I want the users security level to determine which buttons are visible. My problem is if I try to add more than one button.visible = False then the form breaks and I see all but the top button I tried to make invisible. I'm pretty new at coding VBA (I basically just bought a book last week) and I'm hopihn I'm just missing something simple. Can anyone help? Code is below.

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
Dim User As String
Dim UserLevel As Integer
Dim TempPass As String
Dim ID As Integer
Dim workerName As String
Dim TempLoginID As String
Dim SecLevel As String

If IsNull(Me.txtUserName) Then
    MsgBox "Please enter UserName", vbInformation, "Please Enter your HealthcareID this is the same Id you use to log into windows"
    Me.txtUserName.SetFocus
ElseIf IsNull(Me.txtPassword) Then
    MsgBox "Please enter Pin Number", vbInformation, "Please enter your Pin Number"
    Me.txtPassword.SetFocus
Else
    If IsNull(DLookup("UserLogin", "tblUser", "UserLogin = '" & Me.txtUserName.Value & "' And password = '" & Me.txtPassword.Value & "'")) Then
        MsgBox "Invalid UserName or Password! Use your HealthcareID as your username and your pin code to access."
    Else
        TempLoginID = Me.txtUserName.Value
        workerName = DLookup("[UserName]", "tblUser", "[UserLogin] = '" & Me.txtUserName.Value & "'")
        UserSecurity = DLookup("[UserSecurity]", "tblUser", "[UserLogin] = '" & Me.txtUserName.Value & "'")
        TempPass = DLookup("[password]", "tblUser", "[UserLogin] = '" & Me.txtUserName.Value & "'")
        Unit = DLookup("[Unit]", "tblUser", "[UserLogin] = '" & Me.txtUserName.Value & "'")
        Unit = DLookup("[Unit]", "tblUser", "[UserLogin] = '" & Me.txtUserName.Value & "'")
        DoCmd.Close
            Select Case UserSecurity
                Case Is = 1 'Admins
                DoCmd.OpenForm "Navigation Form"
                Forms![Navigation Form]![TxtUser] = workerName
                Forms![Navigation Form]![txtName] = TempLoginID
                Forms![Navigation Form]![txtUnit] = Unit
                Forms![Navigation Form]![txtUserSecurity] = UserSecurity
            ' DoCmd.BrowseTo acBrowseToForm, "frmFirstPage", "Navigation Form.NavigationSubForm", , , acFormEdit
                Case Is = 2 'Managers
                DoCmd.OpenForm "Navigation Form"
                Forms![Navigation Form]![TxtUser] = workerName
                Forms![Navigation Form]![txtName] = TempLoginID
                Forms![Navigation Form]![txtUnit] = Unit
                Forms![Navigation Form]!AdminPageButton.Visible = False
                Forms![Navigation Form]![txtUserSecurity] = UserSecurity
            ' DoCmd.BrowseTo acBrowseToForm, "frmFirstPage", "Navigation Form.NavigationSubForm", , , acFormEdit
                Case Is = 3 'Coordinators
                DoCmd.OpenForm "Navigation Form"
                Forms![Navigation Form]![TxtUser] = workerName
                Forms![Navigation Form]![txtName] = TempLoginID
                Forms![Navigation Form]![txtUnit] = Unit
                Forms![Navigation Form]![txtUserSecurity] = UserSecurity
                Forms![Navigation Form]!btnManagersMenu.Visible = False
                Forms![Navigation Form]!AdminPageButton.Visible = False
            ' DoCmd.BrowseTo acBrowseToForm, "frmFirstPage", "Navigation Form.NavigationSubForm", , , acFormEdit
                Case Else 'RCRs
                DoCmd.OpenForm "Navigation Form"
                Forms![Navigation Form]![TxtUser] = workerName
                Forms![Navigation Form]![txtName] = TempLoginID
                Forms![Navigation Form]![txtUnit] = Unit
                Forms![Navigation Form]![txtUserSecurity] = UserSecurity
                Forms![Navigation Form]!AdminPageButton.Visible = False
                Forms![Navigation Form]!btnManagersMenu.Visible = False
                Forms![Navigation Form]!btnCoordMenu.Visible = False
            ' DoCmd.BrowseTo acBrowseToForm, "frmFirstPage", "Navigation Form.NavigationSubForm", , , acFormEdit
            End Select
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm quite new to Access and VBA myself, so without seeing your navigation form setup I'm not quite sure why your subsequent buttons remain visible when you're opening the form like this.  However, you could try moving your Select Case UserSecurity code into the Form_Load sub of your navigation form - I do something similar with my forms at the Form_Load and Form_Current subs and I have multiple command buttons, text fields etc becoming visible or invisible depending on different criteria, including the users security level.  This is an example of a sub I use on one form -

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
On Error GoTo Form_Current_Err

Me.txtOrderStatus.Requery   'refresh the order status

'move the cursor to the end of the PO No field
 Me.txtPONo.SetFocus
 If Not IsNull(Me.txtPONo) Then
 Me.txtPONo.SelStart = Len(Me.txtPONo)
 End If

'make the contract no and project description fields visible only when the  PO is related to a contract
If txtPOType.Value = "Contract" Then
      Me.txtContractNo.Visible = True
      Me.txtProjectDescription.Visible = True
      Me.txtParentPO.Visible = False
      Me.POTabs.Pages(6).Visible = False
ElseIf Me.txtPOType.Value = "Call Off Order" Then 'make the parent po visible if this is a call off order
        Me.txtContractNo.Visible = False
        Me.txtProjectDescription.Visible = False
        Me.txtParentPO.Visible = True
        Me.POTabs.Pages(6).Visible = True

 Else
      Me.txtContractNo.Visible = False
      Me.txtProjectDescription.Visible = False
      Me.txtParentPO.Visible = False
      Me.POTabs.Pages(6).Visible = False
 End If

 'check if the order is cancelled and hide all action buttons
 If Me.OrderStatus = "Cancelled" Then
 Me.cmdEditPO.Visible = False
 Me.cmdCancelOrder.Visible = False
 Me.txtCancelledOrderFlag.Visible = True
 Me.AmendedOrderFlag.Visible = False
 Else
 Me.cmdEditPO.Visible = True
 Me.txtCancelledOrderFlag.Visible = False

 End If

 'check if this a revised order and hide the Amended Order comment and the PO Revisions subform if it isn't
If txtPORevision > 0 Then
    If Me.OrderStatus <> "Cancelled" Then
    Me.AmendedOrderFlag.Visible = True
    Me.PO_Revisions.Visible = True
    Else
    Me.AmendedOrderFlag.Visible = False
    Me.PO_Revisions.Visible = True
    End If
Else
    Me.AmendedOrderFlag.Visible = False
    Me.PO_Revisions.Visible = False
End If

'check if the PO needs approval and the user is a PO Approver,
' and make the approve/cancel buttons visible as appropriate
If Me.OrderStatus = "For Approval" And _
    (DLookup("Role", "dbo_Employees", "EmployeeID = " & TempVars!EmpID) = "Administrator" _
    Or DLookup("Role", "dbo_Employees", "EmployeeID = " & TempVars!EmpID) = "Manager") Then
    'show the Approve PO button, hide the Cancel button
    Me.cmdApproveOrder.Visible = True
    Me.cmdCancelOrder.Visible = False
Else
'hide the Approve button, show the Cancel button
    Me.cmdApproveOrder.Visible = False
    If Me.OrderStatus <> "Cancelled" Then
    Me.cmdCancelOrder.Visible = True
    End If
End If

'if the order hasn't been approved yet, or is cancelled, hide the email button
If Me.OrderStatus = "New" Or Me.OrderStatus = "Raised" Or Me.OrderStatus = "For Approval" _
Or Me.OrderStatus = "Not Approved" Or Me.OrderStatus = "Cancelled" Then
    Me.cmdEmailPO.Visible = False
Else
    Me.cmdEmailPO.Visible = True
End If

'amend the caption of the Revise order button if the order has not been sent yet
If Me.OrderStatus = "New" Or Me.OrderStatus = "Raised" Then
Me.cmdEditPO.Caption = "Revise/Send Order"
Else
Me.cmdEditPO.Caption = "Revise this Order"
End If

'check if a filter is applied and highlight the filter button if it is
If Me.FilterOn = True Then
Me.cmdApplyFilter.BackColor = vbYellow
Else
Me.cmdApplyFilter.BackThemeColorIndex = 4
Me.cmdApplyFilter.BackShade = 40
Me.cmdApplyFilter.Gradient = 12
End If

'refresh the subform
DoCmd.Requery "PO Details"
```

It also appears that you are setting the txtUser, txtName, txtUnit and txtUserSecurity to the same values in every case, so rather than declaring them multiple times like this, you can just set them as the default values for your controls on the navigation form itself.  You can declare the TempLoginID as a TempVar so that is available to you throughout your database, and that then lets you put the dlookups for the other data anywhere you need them, or lets you set the data for the form to include the User table so you can access them directly without needing dlookup.

Hope that helps a little!

Comment: Based on your answer I was able to find a typo I had made in my code. Thank you!

Comment: glad I could help!